# Ionic Appflow build: fastlane gym error No certificate matching 'iPhone Developer

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor, fastlane, ionic-appflow

in Ionic Appflow we are trying to build our ionic project in iOs. We tried several times and googled for every possible solution but no luck. The error we get is about the signing certificate, we followed those web sites, and we saw that at the first buildings, our  Bundle ID was wrong (before was ourdomain.ourdomain.app  and we were forced to change it to com.ourdomain.ourdomain for iOs).

https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/5701773743255-iOS-build-fails-with-error-App-requires-a-provisioning-profile-Select-a-provisioning-profile-in-the-Signing-Capabilities-editor-in-target-App-from-project-App-v
Even wit hthat fixed, it continues failing and saying the same error, the error message is the following:

"**error: No certificate matching 'iPhone Developer: Here the Firstname and the Lastname (here there is an Id)' found: Select a different signing certificate for CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY, a team that matches your selected certificate, or switch to automatic provisioning. (in target 'CapacitorKeyboard' from project 'Pods')**"
we tried revoking and making new vertificates, new profiles, everything again and again and no luck, for that, we were following the steps dscribed in the folling link:
https://ionic.io/docs/appflow/package/credentials#ios-credentials

we did the openSSL certificates.
We have tried to deleting the string "ios Developer" from the CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY but no luck either. Now its restored.We noticed too that we change the CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY to any king of string, we are getting the same exactly message error, so it seems it dont get the string "iPhone Developer" from there.We also checked in the project.pbxproj that the provisioning is auto -> ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;
Any clue on where can be the issue?
Regards